# How to keep make log and check it online?

Tags: shell, makefile

I want to redirect make's log and see what's doing on make. Here is the script

```
make |& tee make.log         # bash syntax
# make 2>&1 | tee make.log   # or, sh syntax
[ $? -ne 0 ] && echo "Error: stopped" && exit 1
echo "Done"
```

I found it won't execute the Error exit when make failed.
I guess it is caused by the pipe, but how to refine the build script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already restricting yourself to using bash, not portable POSIX sh, you can just use bash's pipefail shell option; run `set -o pipefail`.  The man page for bash says:

> If pipefail is enabled, the pipeline's return status is the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands  exit  successfully.

eg.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o pipefail
if make |& tee make.log ; then
  echo "Done"
else
  echo "Error: stopped"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, Do you know how to do in sh, too?

Comment: There's no straightforward way to do it in POSIX sh.  You can either redirect output through files instead of using pipelines which is much less efficient but lets you test each exit code.  Or you can write the exit code to a file: `(firstcmd; echo $? > exitstatus) | secondcmd` then read the file.  Or you can do something super-fancy with FD duping and redirection; see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another/70675#70675 for example.